# Integrate logarithm of an exponential function?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate  $\displaystyle \int \log(e^x+e^{-x})\,dx $ ?

Comment: Are you actually trying to evaluate some definite integral? Did you try putting it into wolfram alpha?

Comment: Yeah from 0 to pi/4. Wolfram alpha gives a complicated result of the indefinite integral but a numerical value for the definite but, I don't understand what does it mean

Comment: in `MATLAB` the results seems to be equal to `0.6207` by calling `integral(@(x) log(exp(x) + exp(-x)),0,pi/4)`

Comment: @fpe even in Wolframalpha it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$, we have $$\log(e^x + e^{-x}) = \log(e^x(1+e^{-2x})) = x + \log(1+e^{-2x}) = x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1} e^{-2kx}}{k}$$
We now have
\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^a \log(e^x+e^{-x}) dx=\int_0^a \left(x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1} e^{-2kx}}{k}\right) dx\\
& =\dfrac{a^2}2 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \int_0^a e^{-2kx} dx = \dfrac{a^2}2 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \cdot \dfrac{1-e^{-2ka}}{2k}\\
& = \dfrac{a^2}2 + \dfrac{\pi^2}{24} + \dfrac12 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-e^{-2a} \right)^k}{k^2} = \dfrac{a^2}2 + \dfrac{\pi^2}{24} + \dfrac{\text{Li}_2 \left(-e^{-2a} \right)}2
\end{align}

Comment: You may want to explain what a dilogarithm is, in case the OP is not aware of special functions...

Comment: I am not aware of the polylogarithmic function suppose the integral were to find from 0 to pi/4 how do we calculate that?

Comment: Just a query, regarding notation - does $log$ as used here, refer to base $10$ or base $e$? (because the Taylor series expansion used here, depends on this fact).

Comment: @NikhilPanikkar This should be to base e.